# Struggling to get RoR configured correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bundler

I've been searching google for 2 days and still haven't managed to work out what I am doing wrong.

I'm totally new to RoR and following the RoR Tutorial by Michael Hartl

The tutorial requires default gemset...
$ rvm use 2.0.0@railstutorial_rails_4_0 --create --default
Using /Users/mhartl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0 with gemset railstutorial_rails_4_0

I've followed everything as per the instructions and managed to create a new app.  Next step is to modify the gemfile (done)

next I'm told to do a 'Bundle Update'

At this point I get the following error message (before it continues successfully to the end).

Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.1/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": Could not find 'rubygems-bundler' (>= 0) among 52 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Fetching gem metadata....
...
Your bundle is updated

If I try it as sudo bundle update I get this...

```
    /Users/mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems  /dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) among 16 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
from /Users/mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
from /Users/mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
from /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
from /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
from /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

I'm totally baffled.
I've checked on the directory and /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.1/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb" is definitely there.

I know other people are having similar issues, but any help would be very gratefully received, im totally stuck

Comment: can you try `gem install bundler` ?

Comment: Hi Jesse,  I think the problem lies with me trying to follow tutorial instructions and running 'bundle update'  apparently the instructions are wrong.  Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check your **ruby** location, as following:

```
which ruby
```

You should get */home/mike/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby*
Than, check your **rails** location, as following:

```
which rails
```

You should get */home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/rails*
If everything is correct, do the following:

```
gem install bundler
```

When bundler successfully installed, try to create a simple rails application:

```
rails new my_first_app
```

It should create a folder: *my_first_app*

```
cd my_first_app
bundle
rails s
```

It should run a development server on port 3000
Open your browser and visit: **localhost:3000**.

Your Rails should work correctly.

Comment: Which Ruby was correct.  When I try which rails I get the following:  /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin/rails

Comment: It means you created a gemset. It should be fine. Try to do the next steps. BTW, you can see all your gemset, as following: rvm gemset list

Comment: Ok, gone through it and got it to run ok (but for info, that bit ok before too).  When I now go into the gemfile.  Make a tiny change then try 'bundle update'  I still get exactly the same error message... Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.1/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": Could not find 'rubygems-bundler' (>= 0) among 51 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: try to remove Gemfile.lock from your project. Then, run: bundle install

Comment: I've successfully removed gemfile.lock and done bundle install (all ok) - rails s (all ok) - bundle update (still get same error message) (note:  thanks for your persistence, it's really appreciated)

Comment: What version of bundler do you have? Run: gem list bundler.          In general, you should not do update after install. If everything works, you better concentrate on learning rails and not configuring your environment...

Comment: I don't know whether this helps but I've done a rvm gemset list and got the following response:  gemsets for ruby-2.0.0-p195 (found in /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195)
   (default)
   global
=> railstutorial_rails_4_0

Comment: It says bundler (1.3.5) - I'm following this:  http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=4.0#sec-the_first_application (step 1.2.4 - last bit) - it tells me to do a (bundle Update, then a Bundle Install) Once i've modified the Gemfile

Comment: You can absolutely ignore this step. "bundle update" is relevant only when you need to upgrade all your gems (it is usually not done in production). After running 'bundle update', it updates the version of gems in 'Gefmile.lock' file. Best practice, while learning, just remove the Gemfile.lock and run: 'bundle'. It will install all latest gems.

Comment: BRILLIANT - so it's a typo in the training instructions that has caused me all this grief for 2 days.  VERY MANY THANKS, It is much appreciated